# Jul 22 23:53:35 serverNameXXX: svc: unknown version (0 for prog 100003 nfsd)

Tags: centos, linux, nfs

nfs server went down this morning, and it seems that these messages have been appearing in the logs since yesterday. I don't think any changes have been made to the config recently.

```
Jul 22 22:44:50 serverNamexxx kernel: svc: unknown version (0 for prog 100003 nfsd)
Jul 22 22:50:50 serverNamexxx kernel: svc: unknown version (0 for prog 100003 nfsd)
Jul 22 22:57:50 serverNamexxx last message repeated 2 times
```

rpcinfo -p shows the nfs process as having prog id 100003;

```
100003    2   udp   2049  nfs
100003    3   udp   2049  nfs
100003    4   udp   2049  nfs
100003    2   tcp   2049  nfs
100003    3   tcp   2049  nfs
100003    4   tcp   2049  nfs
```

Comment: I'm not seeing this behaviour when I use 'rpcinfo -p' either locally or from a remote host. '-p' uses procedure 2, not 0. I do, however, get your result when using 'rpcinfo -t <hostname> nfs' as well as 'rpcinfo -u <hostname> nfs'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently rpcinfo -p sends version 0 nfsd packets, so that is what is causing the warning.

I am using check_rpc plugin for nagios, and that is where the requests are coming from.